# Arrary push to add a value to an array but its not doing as expected in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

what I want to do is add id = 77 to another array with all

```
Array
(
[77] => 77
) 

 Array
 (
[62] => 62
[84] => 84
[85] => 85
 } 

     $this_user_id = $user['User']['id']; // is 77
     $user_array = array();
     $user_array[$this_user_id] = $user['User']['id']; // creates an array of [77] => 77 

     $group_by_friends = array_push($user_array, $friends_ids); // where frinds_ids are is the second array
     debug($group_by_friends);
```

On a debug mode I'm getting only number "2"
Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do is

```
$group_by_friends = array_merge($user_array, $friends_ids);
```

instead of

```
$group_by_friends = array_push($user_array, '$friends_ids');
```

You get `2` as result, because array_push returns the new number of elements in the array and not a new array. And putting `$friends_ids` in quotes is also wrong - so you add a string to the array and not the array itself.

Here is a full example:

```
$user_array = array();
$user_array[77] = 77; 
$friends_ids = array('88' => 88, '99' => 99);

$group_by_friends = array_merge($user_array, $friends_ids);
print_r($group_by_friends);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 77
    [1] => 88
    [2] => 99
)
```

Comment: I did that before, and no succees.

Comment: I updated my answer with a more detailed info. This solutions works, maybe you had another mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can use + operator.

> The + operator returns the right-hand array appended to the left-hand array; for keys that exist in both arrays, the elements from the left-hand array will be used, and the matching elements from the right-hand array will be ignored.

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

Example

```
$j = array(77 => 77) ;
$k =  array(
  62 => 62,
  84 => 84,
  85 => 85,
  );

$j = $j + $k;
print_r($j);

output:
Array ( [77] => 77 [62] => 62 [84] => 84 [85] => 85 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use array_push() because that expect a mixed value and will not set a key for you.

```js
$userId = $user['User']['id'];
$userArr[$userId] = $userId;

$friendsIdsArray = array();
// assume this has the following
/*
 * $friendsIdsArray[62] => 62
 * $friendsIdsArray[84] => 84
 * $friendsIdsArray[85] => 85
 */

// array_merge
$friendsIdsArray = array_merge($friendsIdsArray, $userArr);

// or set the value yourself
$friendsIdsArray[$userArr] = $userArr;
```